# automate sitecollection administrator assignment in sharepoint online with powershell for backup purposes

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I was asked to create a powershell script to automate the assignment for new sitecollection administrator in SharePoint-Online for BackUp purposes NetApp CloudControl.

This is my firsttime ever in PowerShell and now I got stucked and don't know where to look anymore or least don't understand what I'm looking at.

The script is supposed to do the following:

- Get Microsoft-tenant and password
- Create a new ps-script where the credentials are already filled in
- Connect to sharepoint-online and lookup personal space for every user(onedrive for business sites)
- cut the log and create a second one if more than 200 lines were written
- read the log and make the service-account a sitecollectionadmin
- create task to run the created script once per week

At the moment I got it to do this:

- Get Microsoft-tenant and password
- Save Credentials
- Connect to sharepoint-online and lookup personal space for every user(onedrive for business sites)
- read the log and make the service-account a sitecollectionadministrator

Can anyone of you please help me out on how to proceed with the next steps?

P.S. Please excuse that I'm posting the script as a whole, I just didn't know what I should cut out.

```
$TenantName = $null0
$TenantPassword = $null1
if($TenantName -eq $null0){
    $TenantName = Read-Host "Enter Office 365 - Tenant Name."
    $NewScript = Get-Content $PSCommandPath | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '^\$TenantName = \$null0$',"`$TenantName = '$TenantName'"}
    $NewScript | Out-File $PSCommandPath -Force
}
if($TenantPassword -eq $null1){
    $TenantPassword = Read-Host "Enter Password for netapp-service@$($TenantName).onmicrosoft.com."
    $NewScript = Get-Content $PSCommandPath | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '^\$TenantPassword = \$null1$',"`$TenantPassword = '$TenantPassword'"}
    $NewScript | Out-File $PSCommandPath -Force
}
$username = "netapp-service@$($TenantName).onmicrosoft.com"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $(convertto-securestring $TenantPassword -asplaintext -force)
Connect-SPOService -Url https://$($TenantName)-admin.sharepoint.com/ -Credential $cred
$AdminURI = "https://$($TenantName)-admin.sharepoint.com"
$AdminAccount = "netapp-service@$($TenantName).onmicrosoft.com"
$AdminPass = $TenantPassword
$eDiscoveryUser = "netapp-service@$($TenantName).onmicrosoft.com"
$MySitePrefix = "https://$($TenantName)-my.sharepoint.com"
$LogFile = '.\$TenantName\$TenantName-MySites.txt'
$MySiteListFile = '.\$TenantName\$TenantName-MySites.txt'
Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminURI -Credential $cred
$loadInfo1 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
$loadInfo2 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
$loadInfo3 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles")
$sstr = ConvertTo-SecureString -string $AdminPass -AsPlainText –Force
$AdminPass = ""
$creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($AdminAccount, $sstr)
$proxyaddr = "$AdminURI/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx?wsdl"
$UserProfileService= New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $proxyaddr -UseDefaultCredential False
$UserProfileService.Credentials = $creds
$strAuthCookie = $creds.GetAuthenticationCookie($AdminURI)
$uri = New-Object System.Uri($AdminURI)
$container = New-Object System.Net.CookieContainer
$container.SetCookies($uri, $strAuthCookie)
$UserProfileService.CookieContainer = $container
$UserProfileResult = $UserProfileService.GetUserProfileByIndex(-1)
Write-Host "Starting- This could take a while."
Out-File $LogFile -Force
$NumProfiles = $UserProfileService.GetUserProfileCount()
$i = 1
While ($UserProfileResult.NextValue -ne -1) 
{
Write-Host "Examining profile $i of $NumProfiles"
$Prop = $UserProfileResult.UserProfile | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "PersonalSpace" } 
$Url= $Prop.Values[0].Value
if ($Url) {
$Url | Out-File $LogFile -Append -Force
}
$UserProfileResult = $UserProfileService.GetUserProfileByIndex($UserProfileResult.NextValue)
$i++
}
Write-Host "Done!"
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($MySiteListFile)
try {
    for(;;) {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        if ($line -eq $null) { break }
        $fullsitepath = "$MySitePrefix$line"
Write-Host "Operating on $fullsitepath "
$fullsitepath = $fullsitepath.trimend("/")
Write-Host "Making $eDiscoveryUser a Site Collection Admin"
Set-SPOUser -Site $fullsitepath -LoginName $eDiscoveryUser -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $true
    }
}
finally {
    $reader.Close()
}
Disconnect-SPOService
Write-Host "Done!"
```

Comment: That's a little too broad. What would you like to continue with, what have you tried and where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to be more precise.
At the moment, I tried extracting the script into a new file with Out-File, but this messed up the script as a whole with all the displayed information also getting copied into the new file, so the created .ps1 doesn't work.
Also I don't want the original script to keep the read-host entries after its done running.